# How to interpret accelerometer data to get decimals from -255 to 255

Tags: arduino-ide

I'm using gy-521 module and I'm wondering how can i get useful readings from it so that i could work with the data that I'm receiving.

I want for AcX and AcY variable values to be from -255 to 255.
How to make this work.

sample data that I'm getting right now

```
X = 16380 Y = -64
X = 8116 Y = 3520
X = 12564 Y = 8728
X = -12652 Y = 1296
X = -17732 Y = -2420
X = -14576 Y = -2264
```

;

```
#include<Wire.h>
const int MPU_addr=0x68;
int16_t AcX,AcY;
void setup(){
  Wire.begin();
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x6B); 
  Wire.write(0);     
  Wire.endTransmission(true);
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop(){
  Wire.beginTransmission(MPU_addr);
  Wire.write(0x3B);  // starting with register 0x3B (ACCEL_XOUT_H)
  Wire.endTransmission(false);
  Wire.requestFrom(MPU_addr,14,true);  
  AcX=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  
  AcY=Wire.read()<<8|Wire.read();  

  Serial.print("X = "); Serial.print(AcX);
  Serial.print(" Y = "); Serial.println(AcY);

  delay(333);
}
```

Comment: And what are the values you are actually getting from it?

Comment: X = 16380 Y = -64
X = 8116 Y = 3520
X = 12564 Y = 8728
X = -12652 Y = 1296
X = -17732 Y = -2420
X = -14576 Y = -2264

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this code:

```cpp
AcX = map(AcX, -32768, 32767, -255, 255);
AcY = map(AcY, -32768, 32767, -255, 255);
```

Of course, you won't be able to store the resulting value in `int8_t` since its range is from -128 to 127.

[Here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/Map) you can read more about Arduino `map()` function.

Comment: Or just divide the values by 128 (the same as a right-shift by 7 bits).

Comment: That is correct. However, by using `map()` you can tweak the input/output ranges. The sensor maybe doesn't return values below some threshold and in that case using shift would result in lower resolution of the output.

Comment: could you give me an example

Comment: For example, if you notice the sensor never returns values below -25000 you can use `AcX = map(AcX, -25000, 25000, -255, 255);` to increase the output resolution. Of course, the maximum value that sensor returns, in that case must not be above +25000. If the maximum value is e.g. 26000 then you must use `AcX = map(AcX, -26000, 26000, -255, 255);`